# SQL Server 2008 Edition Upgrade Enterprise Evaluation to Standard problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

On my Windows Server 2012 machine SQL Server 2008 evaluation time has expired. After Edition Upgrade nothing happens, SQL Service doesn't start. In service log still is information about expired evaluation time. Upgrade log contains information about pending installation. Nothing happens after server restart. I want to avoid re-installation of SQL Server. Logs below:

Edit:
After changing of current date on server and restarting machine SQL Services started. Select @@version returns information that SQL is still in "Evaluation Enterprise" version. 
After Edition Upgrade and instance restart still that same information("Evaluation Enterprise" version) and Final result marked as Pending.

Overall summary:

```
  Final result:                  Pending
  Exit code (Decimal):           0
  Exit message:                  Pending
  Start time:                    2015-07-05 00:15:23
  End time:                      2015-07-05 00:16:54
  Requested action:              EditionUpgrade
```

Machine Properties:

```
  Machine name:                  SERVER
  Machine processor count:       4
  OS version:                    Future Windows Version
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   polski (Polska)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No
```

Product features discovered:

```
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 
  Sql Server 2008      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER            Database Engine Services                 1033                 Enterprise Evaluation Edition 10.0.1600.22    No        
  Sql Server 2008      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER            SQL Server Replication                   1033                 Enterprise Evaluation Edition 10.0.1600.22    No        
  Sql Server 2008      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER            Full-Text Search                         1033                 Enterprise Evaluation Edition 10.0.1600.22    No        
  Sql Server 2008      MSSQLSERVER          MSAS10.MSSQLSERVER             Analysis Services                        1033                 Enterprise Evaluation Edition 10.0.1600.22    No        
  Sql Server 2008      MSSQLSERVER          MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER             Reporting Services                       1033                 Enterprise Evaluation Edition 10.0.1600.22    No        
  Sql Server 2008 R2                                                       Management Tools - Basic                 1033                 Standard Edition     10.50.1600.1    No        
  Sql Server 2008 R2                                                       Management Tools - Complete              1033                 Standard Edition     10.50.1600.1    No        
  Sql Server 2008                                                          Integration Services                     1033                 Enterprise Evaluation Edition 10.0.1600.22    No
```

Package properties:

```
  Description:                   SQL Server Database Services 2008 R2
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2008 R2
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       10
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         E:\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          STANDARD
```

User Input Settings:

```
  ACTION:                        EditionUpgrade
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150705_001505\ConfigurationFile.ini
  ENU:                           True
  FARMACCOUNT:                   <empty>
  FARMADMINPORT:                 0
  FARMPASSWORD:                  *****
  FEATURES:                      SSMS,ADV_SSMS,SNAC_SDK,OCS,CE_RUNTIME,CE_TOOLS,SNAC
  HELP:                          False
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  False
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              False
  INSTANCENAME:                  <empty>
  PASSPHRASE:                    *****
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         False
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   False
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  X86:                           False
```

Configuration file:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150705_001505\ConfigurationFile.ini
```

Detailed results:

```
  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
  Status:                        Skipped
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Skipped
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Compact Edition Tools
  Status:                        Skipped
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Compact Edition Runtime
  Status:                        Skipped
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Management Tools - Complete
  Status:                        Passed
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Management Tools - Basic
  Status:                        Passed
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Microsoft Sync Framework
  Status:                        Skipped
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed
```

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

There are no scenario-specific rules.

Rules report file:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150705_001505\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Service log

```
2015-07-05 08:16:40.67 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64) 
    Jul  9 2008 14:17:44 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Evaluation Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )

2015-07-05 08:16:40.67 Server      (c) 2005 Microsoft Corporation.
2015-07-05 08:16:40.67 Server      All rights reserved.
2015-07-05 08:16:40.67 Server      Server process ID is 13840.
2015-07-05 08:16:40.67 Server      System Manufacturer: 'Supermicro', System Model: 'X9DRD-7LN4F(-JBOD)/X9DRD-EF'.
2015-07-05 08:16:40.67 Server      Authentication mode is MIXED.
2015-07-05 08:16:40.67 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
2015-07-05 08:16:40.67 Server      Error: 17051, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2015-07-05 08:16:40.67 Server      SQL Server evaluation period has expired.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a hunch that you changed system date to workaround with evaluation period expired message and then you forgot to change it back. After this you did edition upgardea and this some how changed registries to incorrect value.

As per logs the system has been upgraded with `NO FAILURE` but problem lies with SSMS.

[SQl Server support team has written article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971268#/en-us/kb/971268) to overcome this issue please read the article. I am posting a snippet which would help you, but **before proceeding please read complete support article**

> 1.Click Start, click Run, type Regedt32, and then click OK.
>
> 2.Locate and then click the following key in the Registry Editor:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\ConfigurationState
>   3.In the right pane of the Registry Editor, select CommonFiles DWord value.
>
> 4.On the Edit menu, click Modify.
>
> 5.Type 3, and then click OK.
>
> 6.Quit Registry Editor.
>
> 7.Rerun the edition upgrade procedure to complete the upgrade of all the components to a licensed edition.
>
> 8.After the edition upgrade is complete, refer to the following Knowledge Base article to prevent issues with future updates to the
>   instance.
>
> 970608 Updates to Microsoft SQL server 2008 will fail after an edition
>   upgrade

**NOTE**

Please avoid changing Windows server/Client OS time to overcome `Evaluation expired message` this could lead to database instability specially if you use column which has `date,datetime` as column type defined as this will get incorrect values